# Express handlerbars node js question with <a href=>

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-handlebars

I have succesfully parsed my shopify product items into mongodb database using a model and i am trying to output them using express-handlebars package to show them into the user.

I have a small problem though.

I use `<td><a href="{{this.product_link}}">{{this.title}}</a></td>`

To show a link with product title so user can click on it and go to the product on the request page.

When i put the link it goes to localhost:5000/www.shop.myshopify.com/products/....

instead of www.shop.myshopify.com/products/... and therefore i am getting a cannot get request back.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you have in `this.product_link`?

Comment: check what this `{{this.product_link}}` code prints. maybe there is a `/` in front of the string.

Comment: this.product_link has www.shop.myshopify.com\products\pretty-big-doll and it's string defined in Mongodb. has no / before www.  Strange thing is if i leave <a href=" "> </a> it redirects the user to localhost:5000 :S

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found the answer and it's pretty simple.

Because i had the link as www.shop.myshopify.com/products/.... instead of https://www.shop.myshopify.com/products/.... wasn't rendering it properly so it was going to get / from node.js server and what was getting from there.